# My app is getting shut down when i try to resume after some time passed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I figured out what kind of circumstance makes this happen

First i start my app and after finishing loading i go to home screen and do something else
and after 15 minutes i reopen my app and it works fine without showing splash activity.
It seems like the app just resume so it doesn't need to load from the beginning

Weird thing happens if i wait 30 minutes before reopening my app.
When i reopen my app after 30 minutes waiting, my app shows loading page like from the beginning and then it just gets shut down before it shows main page.

I really tried to solve this problem by myself but it doesn't show the same result if i use android studio for debugging. It just works fine and it never shows first activity no matter how long i wait it just enters to the main activity right away.

So i really don't know where to start looking for to solve this problem

Comment: The logcat will still show what have happened if you connect the smartphone when the app crashes and check the errors

Comment: This seems like a description of how most Android apps work (some do their own special state restoration).  What's different with yours vs. other apps on your phone?

Comment: Look in logcat after the app crashes. You should see the reason for the crash with stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, apps don't stay in your RAM forever. Sometime it will eventually be turned off by the memory management. It will have to restart from the starting activity.

Secondly, you have not posted code of your starting activity so that we can diagnose whats wrong. You can post the code here. 
But I am not clear of your question. You say app directly goes into the main activity [assuming your first activity was a splash screen], looks like it still in RAM.

**I would suggest you to paste the code here so that I can test further.**
Your app loads directly into main activity sometimes but crashes the other times. That's awkward.
The case might differ on what's usage of RAM at that time and what other apps are on.